# C with gcc and Portuguese Characters

Tags: c, widechar

I am trying to print and read from the windows console Portuguese character such as: ç , é and so on...

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <locale.h>
    #include <wchar.h>

int main (void){
        wchar_t stringtemp[5];
        setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");


        wprintf(L"test with portuguese character: ç\n");
        wprintf(L"Insert a strange portuguese character: ");
        wscanf(L"%s",stringtemp);
        wprintf(L"%s\n",stringtemp);

        return 0;
    }
```

Here is the output:

test with portuguese character: ç

Insert a strange portuguese character: ç

╬

someone knows what is wrong there?

Comment: `1` I suppose the `inserirNovoRegisto` part are not very relevant? Remove it please. `2` A [mcve] contains `#include<stdio.h>
#include<wchar.h>
#include<locale.h>`.

Comment: [Unfortunately, cannot repro on TIO](https://tio.run/##dc6xisJAEAbgfp9iiAgRVGyuuYSAWAkp7FVk2cwlC3ESdiZaiM/jg/hgMRshEuS2/Pf/ZsYscmPadmLJlE2GMUtmq2WRqCG5mkK7UVJWRpfoI2VJ4KwtQXipbDa7KeheL04CLM5SLniu9z/HqP9ilLcO081pnabzYFc5afIGGYNZpN6@7pz8hWkgyAJXKwXUQw38dG0E3S88HwfybKy2xOgEtD9AU47/4AGy0eTdlIP55@avsUky5TjuFo5LfcuhNI5gFal72z4fLw). Maybe Windows specific.

Comment: @user202729 , TIO my output was even worst... test with portuguese character: ?
Insert a strange portuguese character: >><<

Comment: (I added the `>>` and `<<` to make sure I don't miss anything)

Comment: Probably an issue with your locale

Comment: @user202729 I know. The thing is between >>and<< theres is nothing ... trying on TIO

Comment: Which operating system?.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch on windows 10

Answer (score 2):

On Linux at least, your code above works if I change the line that says `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese")` to `setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR.UTF-8")`.

(Oddly enough, it did not work with `"pt_PT.UTF-8"`).

Comment: Tested on ubuntu and it worked. Exactly the same code with the change you suggestted... On ubuntu works, on windows not. I am wondering if there are a work around for Windows..

Answer (score 1):

Use this - `setlocale(LC_ALL,"pl_PL.UTF-8");`

Comment: did you try `pl_PL.UTF-8`?

Comment: if I changed that getting the ç (from wscanf for example) works, but wprintf doen't work anymore...